# Create table for asclogit and nlogit

Tags: stata

Suppose I have the following table:

```
id | car      | sex    | income
-------------------------------
1  | European | Male   | 45000
2  | Japanese | Female | 48000
3  | American | Male   | 53000
```

I would like to create the one below:

```
  | id | car      | choice | sex    | income
--------------------------------------------
1.| 1  | European | 1      | Male   | 45000
2.| 1  | American | 0      | Male   | 45000
3.| 1  | Japanese | 0      | Male   | 45000
  | ----------------------------------------
4.| 2  | European | 0      | Female | 48000
5.| 2  | American | 0      | Female | 48000
6.| 2  | Japanese | 1      | Female | 48000
  | ----------------------------------------
7.| 3  | European | 0      | Male   | 53000
8.| 3  | American | 1      | Male   | 53000
9.| 3  | Japanese | 0      | Male   | 53000
```

I would like to fit an `asclogit` and according to [Example 1](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rasclogit.pdf) in Stata's Manual, this table format seems necessary. However, i have not found a way to create this easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `cross` command to generate all the possible combinations:

```
clear

input byte id str10 car str8 sex long income
1 "European" "Male"   45000
2 "Japanese" "Female" 48000
3 "American" "Male"   53000
end

generate choice = 0
save old, replace

keep id
save new, replace

use old
rename id =_0
cross using new

replace choice = 1 if id_0 == id
replace sex = cond(id == 2, "Female", "Male")
replace income = cond(id == 1, 45000, cond(id == 2, 48000, 53000))
```

Note that the use of the `cond()` function here is equivalent to:

```
replace sex = "Male"   if id == 1
replace sex = "Female" if id == 2
replace sex = "Male"   if id == 3

replace income = 45000 if id == 1
replace income = 48000 if id == 2
replace income = 53000 if id == 3
```

The above code snipped produces the desired output:

```
drop id_0
order id car choice sex income
sort id car

list, sepby(id)

     +------------------------------------------+
     | id        car   choice      sex   income |
     |------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1   American        0     Male    45000 |
  2. |  1   European        1     Male    45000 |
  3. |  1   Japanese        0     Male    45000 |
     |------------------------------------------|
  4. |  2   American        0   Female    48000 |
  5. |  2   European        0   Female    48000 |
  6. |  2   Japanese        1   Female    48000 |
     |------------------------------------------|
  7. |  3   American        1     Male    53000 |
  8. |  3   European        0     Male    53000 |
  9. |  3   Japanese        0     Male    53000 |
     +------------------------------------------+
```

For more information, type `help cross` and `help cond()` from Stata's command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Please see `dataex` in Stata for how to produce data examples useful in web forums. (If necessary, install first using `ssc install dataex`.)

This could be an exercise in using `fillin` followed by filling in the missings.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte id str10 car str8 sex long income
1 "European" "Male"   45000
2 "Japanese" "Female" 48000
3 "American" "Male"   53000
end

fillin id car

foreach v in sex income {
    bysort id (_fillin) : replace `v' = `v'[1]
}

list , sepby(id)

     +-------------------------------------------+
     | id        car      sex   income   _fillin |
     |-------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1   European     Male    45000         0 |
  2. |  1   American     Male    45000         1 |
  3. |  1   Japanese     Male    45000         1 |
     |-------------------------------------------|
  4. |  2   Japanese   Female    48000         0 |
  5. |  2   European   Female    48000         1 |
  6. |  2   American   Female    48000         1 |
     |-------------------------------------------|
  7. |  3   American     Male    53000         0 |
  8. |  3   European     Male    53000         1 |
  9. |  3   Japanese     Male    53000         1 |
     +-------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A provisional solution using `Pandas` in Python is the following:

1) Open the base with:

```
df = pd.read_stata("mybase.dta")
```

2) Use the code of the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50551728/pandas-create-a-table-with-a-dummy-variable).

3) Save the base:

```
df.to_stata("newbase.dta")
```

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to use dummy variables, `reshape` also is an option.

```
clear
input byte id str10 car str8 sex long income
1 "European" "Male"   45000
2 "Japanese" "Female" 48000
3 "American" "Male"   53000
end

tabulate car, gen(choice)
reshape long choice, i(id)

label define car 2 "European" 3 "Japanese" 1 "American"
drop car
rename _j car
label values car car
```

> ```
> list, sepby(id)
> ```

```
     +------------------------------------------+
     | id        car      sex   income   choice |
     |------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1   American     Male    45000        0 |
  2. |  1   European     Male    45000        1 |
  3. |  1   Japanese     Male    45000        0 |
     |------------------------------------------|
  4. |  2   American   Female    48000        0 |
  5. |  2   European   Female    48000        0 |
  6. |  2   Japanese   Female    48000        1 |
     |------------------------------------------|
  7. |  3   American     Male    53000        1 |
  8. |  3   European     Male    53000        0 |
  9. |  3   Japanese     Male    53000        0 |
     +------------------------------------------+
```