# Pandas - Create a table with a "dummy variable"

Tags: python, pandas, stata

Let's say I have this dataframe

```
id | car      | sex    | income
-------------------------------
1  | European | Male   | 45000
2  | Japanese | Female | 48000
3  | American | Male   | 53000
```

Is there an easy way to create this one (using pandas) ?

```
  | id | car      | choice | sex    | income
1.| 1  | European | 1      | Male   | 45000
2.| 1  | American | 0      | Male   | 45000
3.| 1  | Japanese | 0      | Male   | 45000
  | ----------------------------------------
4.| 2  | European | 0      | Female | 48000
5.| 2  | American | 0      | Female | 48000
6.| 2  | Japanese | 1      | Female | 48000
  | ----------------------------------------
7.| 3  | European | 0      | Male   | 53000
8.| 3  | American | 1      | Male   | 53000
9.| 3  | Japanese | 0      | Male   | 53000
```

The idea is to get every modality of the "car" variable in the base, and to indicate which one every person has chosen through the "choice" variable. For example, in the first table, the person with the `id` 1 has chosen an European car, so `choice` equals 1 in the line where `car` is European, and zero in the line where `car` equals American or Japanese.

I already coded something which manually does it (using a dictionary) but I wanted to know if a cleaner solution exists.

(This has for aim to format the data in order to use an asclogit/nlogit under Stata)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe need:

```
df = df.assign(choice = 1).set_index(['id','car'])
df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names))

df = (df.assign(choice=df['choice'].fillna(0).astype(int))
        .groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   id       car     sex   income  choice
0   1  American    Male  45000.0       0
1   1  European    Male  45000.0       1
2   1  Japanese    Male  45000.0       0
3   2  American  Female  48000.0       0
4   2  European  Female  48000.0       0
5   2  Japanese  Female  48000.0       1
6   3  American    Male  53000.0       1
7   3  European    Male  53000.0       0
8   3  Japanese    Male  53000.0       0
```

**Explanation**:

1.First create new column with `1` by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)
2.Create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
3.Generate all possible combination by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and create new rows by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)
4.Then replace `NaN`s to `0` in `choice` column
5.Last replace `NaN`s in all another columns by forward and backfilling.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're referring to random binary integers rather than 'dummy variables'. 'dummy variables' are usually used to assign a numeric variable to non-numerical values. ([Dummy Variables](https://socialresearchmethods.net/kb/dummyvar.php))

If you are trying to assign random binary integers to a new empty column,  you can use `numpy.random.rand` ([Numpy.random.rand](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html))

As an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'B': ['b', 'a', 'c'],'C': [1, 2, 3]})
  A  B  C
0 a  b  1
1 b  a  2
3 a  c  3

df['randNumCol'] = np.random.randint(0,1, size=len(df))

  A  B  C randNumCol
0 a  b  1     0
1 b  a  2     1 
3 a  c  3     0
```

Specify range of random integers to 0,1

Comment: This is not what I expected, but thanks :) ! I edited my post and gave more precision